# if statement in a foreach

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a sub function that allows the user to type in certain things and the function will search a file for lines that contain them. The main problem that I am having is the if statement within the foreach statement. My main goal is see if the three variables that the user typed in matches to certain columns within a file. If they do, then certain columns would be taken out to their specific variable.

My data looks like this:

```
ATOM   4851  O   PRO A 715      89.164  76.083  75.292  1.00 99.41           O  
ATOM   4852  CB  PRO A 715      88.324  78.267  73.865  1.00 95.88           C  
ATOM   4853  CG  PRO A 715      88.836  78.838  72.540  1.00 95.93           C
```

For example, if the user types in PRO A 715, then the foreach would go through all lines and the if statement would look to meet those conditions and then the coordinates would be taken out.

x coordinates: 89.164, 88.324, 88.836

y coordinates: 76.083, 78.267, 78.838

z coordinates: 75.292, 73.865, 72.540

My error that I get for this is:

```
Can't modify logical and (&&) in scalar assignment at ./pdbtool.pl line 75, near ") ) "
```

My program is:

```
open (FILE, $ARGV[0])
    or die "Could not open file\n";

my @newlines;
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
    if ($line =~ m/^ATOM.*/) {
    push @newlines, $line;
    }
}

sub reslength {
#User will type in the information
print "Type Residue Name:\n";
my $residue = <STDIN>;
chomp($residue);
print "Type Chain ID:\n";
my $chainid = <STDIN>;
chomp ($chainid);
print "Type Residue Sequence Number\n";
my $resseq = <STDIN>;
chomp ($resseq);

#The function will go through each line and match the info along with pushing it to a new vairable
my @arrayx;
my @arrayy;
my @arrayz;

    foreach my $record3(@newlines) {
      if ( $residue = substr($record3, 17, 3) && $chainid = substr($record3, 21, 1) && $resseq = substr($record3, 22, 4) ) {
            @arrayx = substr($record3, 30, 8);
            @arrayy = substr($record3, 38, 8);
            @arrayz = substr($record3, 46, 8);
            }
    }
#Now I will find the distance between these x,y,z coordinates
my $distance = sqrt[(@arrayx(1)-@arrayx(0))^2 + (@arrayy(1)-@arrayy(0))^2 + (@arrayz(1)-@arrayz(0))^2)]
print "$resname with sequence number $resseq in $chainid has length $distance angstroms.\n"
```

}

Comment: This code needs rewriting I think. Can you clarify which of the coordinates from your example need to have the distance computed? I can't figure out how you're using a 3-coordinate example, and then only trying to use two of them in the sqrt.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 of troubleshooting perl is turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;` as this will tell you about problems with your code.

Your snippet of code with the `sqrt` is almost certainly a problem, because you're using the wrong sort of brackets, and have omitted a semicolon.

However in addition:

- you define a sub `reslength` put most of your code in it, and then never actually call it.
- You use `=` in a comparison, instead of `==`. `=` is an *assignment* where `==` is a comparison.
- `substr` matching something whitespace delimited is brittle. Try regex or `split`.
- you should use `(` when calling `sqrt`.
- You should use `[` when looking at array indicies.
- You are opening a file as specified on `$ARGV[0]` - you should probably consider just using `<>` which does the same thing (but will also do multiple files).
- You're reading a file into an array, and then iterating that array. Why not just iterate the file?
- You should use 3 argument open with lexical file handles.

So as a starter for 10 - this will read your coordinates into an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

#replace this bit with your 'user input' once you're done testing. 

my $residue = 'PRO';
my $chainid = 'A';
my $resseq = '715'; 

my @coords; 

open ( my $input, '<', $ARGV[0] ) or die $!; 
while ( <$input> ) {

   next unless m/^ATOM/; 
   my @fields = split;
   my ( $res, $chain, $seq, $x_coord, $y_coord, $z_coord ) = @fields[3..8];

   next unless $residue eq $res;
   next unless $chainid eq $chain;
   next unless $resseq eq $seq; 

   #insert into array of coordinates. Could flip order, and 
   push ( @{$coords[0]}, $x_coord );
   push ( @{$coords[1]}, $y_coord );
   push ( @{$coords[2]}, $z_coord );

}
close ( $input );

#print for debugging - what have we read in.     
print Dumper \@coords;


my $distance = sqrt ( ( $coords[0][1] - $coords[0][0]  ) ^ 2
                    + ( $coords[1][1] - $coords[1][0] ) ^ 2
                    + ( $coords[2][1] - $coords[2][0] ) ^ 2 );

print "$residue with sequence number $resseq in $chainid has length $distance angstroms.\n"
```

Problem with this, that it ignores your third row entirely. But your code seems to too, so I'm not really sure what you wanted to do with that.

But this outputs:

```
PRO with sequence number 715 in A has length 2.44948974278318 angstroms.
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant modify a variable within an if statement like that.
I think you might want to be doing a comparison check.

```
if ( $residue == substr($record3, 17, 3) && $chainid == substr($record3, 21, 1) && $resseq == substr($record3, 22, 4) )
```

This however brings forth another error with $distance
To access a a variable in a array you should use $array[$num]

```
my $distance = sqrt[($arrayx[1]-$arrayx[0])^2 + ($arrayy[1]-$arrayy[0])^2 + ($arrayz[1]-$arrayz[0])^2];
```

Comment: "_You cant modify a variable within an if statement like that_" -- well, you can assign inside `if`, even declare, `if ((my $v = func(...)) != $num) { .. $v .. }`, where parens around assignment are necessary.  But you are right that OP seems to need `==`, not `=`.